# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.endpointPrefix

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect my andoid app to dynamo db for CRUD operation  when I click on any button it throws, "Unforutunately app stopped working" from my android device with following log at backend[log cat]

> Process: com.connect.dynamodb.connecttodynamodb, PID: 16283
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   ***com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.endpointPrefix
>   at***
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.init(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:460)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:444)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:392)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:361)

***I created identity pool,account id,auth user and unauth user roles
Configurations done are as follows for Cognito***

Try 1 :

```
> CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentials = new
> CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context,
>                 "accountId",
>                 Constants.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
>                 "Unauth_Role",
>                 "Auth_Role",
>                 Regions.US_EAST_1);
>         ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
>         ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
```

Try 2:

> ```
>     CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentials = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
>             context,
>             "IDENTITY_POOL_ID",
>             Regions.US_EAST_1);
>
>     ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
>     ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
> }
> ```

Both tries are not working .Any help would be appreciated.I am referring following link.

Ref : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference_Cognito/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding

```
> compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
> compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
> compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
```

and adding `aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper-2.4.7.jar` to lib folder and  setting the region to `Regions.AP_SOUTH_1`, where I have created the identity pool.

Comment: compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+' is also available

Comment: Yes Donkon I used it inside the lib folder.

Comment: what I mean is: You don't need to have the jar, the artifact is also available through maven just like the core, s3, and ddb

Comment: Sorry Donkon I got it at first only but forgot to edit the comment.Yes I will try to add dependency  in gradle file and remove the jar in lib .Thnx